# individual score board system

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway that i can make a scoreboard show up just with that person on there. I don't want to have everyone show up on one score board but also don't want to have to make a lot of score boards.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Kills totalKillCount
/scoreboard objectives setDisplay sidebar Kills
```

This should show how many kills each player has. If the player has 0 kills they won't show up until they get a kill. I don't think it's possible to do this.

> "make a scoreboard show up just with that person on there. I don't want to have everyone show up on one score board but also don't want to have to make a lot of score boards."